# Default User on IIS 6.0 for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-6

I am getting an error that I can't write to one of my temp folders due to permissions. I am using IIS 6.0 and ASP.NET 3.5 and I have set the write permissions to [COMPUTERNAME]\ASPNET but still nothing. If I set the user to Everyone with full control it works but can't do that for security reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS_User is the user name you have to give permission to

Comment: Thanks I figure it out too. I had to make it IUSR_[COMPNAME] but had to switch the location to the computer name and not the users directory.